# StreamTokenizer, rendering a html file?

Tags: java, html, regex, rendering, html-parsing

I am making a HTML renderer. I have the html file being read into a StreamTokenizer. At the moment it prints out the correct tokens, and in my html file specify my varbiles enclosed in dollars e.g

```
<html><p>$myVarToBeRendered$<p></html>
```

I get the correct tokens i.e it splits up the html body and vars by using the quoteChar('$')

```
FileReader in = new FileReader(file); 
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(in); 
    StreamTokenizer tok;
    tok = new StreamTokenizer(reader);
    tok.resetSyntax();
    tok.wordChars(0, 255); 
    tok.quoteChar('$');
```

I get the string tokens

```
"<html><p>" , "myVarToBeRendered" and "<p></html>"
```

Though when reading through the token i obviously need to replace the myVar token which is identified as a quote. This myVar is used as a key in a HashMap holding the string values to be rendered to each variable. Is there a way of checking if a token is a quote? like:

```
if (tok.next - is a quote or inside my quotes)
     Then replace this var name with its related HashMap value
```

I have scoured the internet and can't find any examples or similar questions to help me along!

Or any method I could use so I can identify which tokens are variables to used in the HashMap. Sorry if this doesn't make sense, hope you understand what i'm trying to do!!

Many Thanks Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I misunderstood the question, but you can check the presence of your tokens in a map by simply calling myMap.containsKey(myVarToBeRendered).

On a separate note, I think using regex Pattern matching to extract substitution vars from your html seems like a better idea than using StreamTokenizer.

Comment: yah thats a good idea using the containsKey, i forgot about that method!, I was going to use regex but it means loading the file first as a string then checking?. My reasoning was when loading the FileStream is would be more efficient to modify it whilst loading